# Is there a reason to use different sets of resistor values in the 2 stages of a butterworth LPF?

Tags: filter, low-pass, active-filter

I needed a LPF for my design so I used Filter Design Tool from AD to generate one. The generated circuit includes 2 sets of resistors of different values, which I find inconvenient. Is there a reason that the tool does this? If yes, what is the reason?

Generated filter:

[image]

Filter parameters:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a poor piece of software. First of all, it suggests component values that aren't available. You are never gonna find a \$1.66 \: \text{k}\Omega\$ resistor on the shelf. Second of all, with the resistors not being equal in this Sallen-Key configuration the filter will be sensitive to component drift.

Answer (score 4):

> *If yes, what is the reason?*

You are trying to design a 4th order Butterworth low pass filter using cascaded 2nd order stages.

Because of this, the 2nd order filters have significantly different Q-factors (even though their cut-off frequencies are the same): -

[image]

Modified image source: [Butterworth filter table](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Butterworth-Filter-Table_fig15_264896983).

Look at the red part I've highlighted; there are two stages and their respective Q-factors are 0.5412 and 1.3065. This is the reason why the two stages have different resistor values to each other. It's all part of the Butterworth design; the two Q-factors multiply to produce a net Q of 0.7071. All Butterworth filters have to meet this criteria or, they ain't Butterworth!

As for each stage using two different resistors, this is because you have chosen the two capacitors to be in a ratio of 10:1. This ratio creates an excessive Q-factor for a Butterworth filter and, this is reduced by the resistors not having the same value.